# The index html file is not being generated with HtmlWebpackPlugin in Linux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have a react project and while building the project, this command runs:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  template: 'public/index.html',
  minify: {
    removeComments: true,
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
    useShortDoctype: true,
    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    keepClosingSlash: true,
    minifyJS: true,
    minifyCSS: true,
    minifyURLs: true
  },
  filename: '/index.' + Date.now() + '.html'
}),
```

When I build the project in Windows, it generates the fingerprinted index file like `index.1514560078687.html` inside the folder `build` along with other assets and files.
But, when I run it in Ubuntu, it generates all files but the index file. Even if I set `filename: '/index.html'`, it won't be generated.

Any idea?

Comment: `/index.` - have you checked _root_ folder on your Ubuntu? cuz it seems weird to me. You can try to add `.` before you `index` file like `./index.`

Comment: @TheReason. That's a good point. But, as I know, it will be added to the `build` path. However, I'm gonna try it

Comment: @TheReason, Actually, you're right. It works well now. you deserve up-votes :). Please put your comment as an answer to let me select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `HtmlWebpackPlugin` stores `index.html` file in your *root* directory. Have you checked it?

Try to add `.` before `/index.html` it might work for you.